# Why do we need both bitmasks and keyed hash in SPHINCS+

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature, one-time-signature

I think one of them is related to multitarget attacks and the other is related to collision attacks. But I cannot find how hash based crypto related to hash collisions.

1-) Consider the following Lamport one time signature scheme

- Assume a 128 bit hash function $H$  is used
- Randomly choose $p_i$ and $r_i $ for $1\leq i \leq 128$
- $SK=\{(p_i,r_i)\}_i$ is the secret key and $PK=\{(H(p_i),H(r_i))\}_i$ is the public key.
- For the message $M$, we take the hash $h=H(M)$. Let $h=h_1h_2\cdots h_{128}$
- For signing $M$, we publish $p_i$ if $h_i=0$ and $r_i$ if $h_i=1$ for each $i$.

How the adversary can apply $2^{64}$-cost attack?

What is the security of this scheme? (I think 120-bit because multitarget applies i.e. it is enough to find at least one of $p_i,r_i$'s. A random guess has prob $\frac{256}{2^{128}}$)

2-) Consider the original Merkle tree with $2^{10}$ Lamport one time signatures without bitmasks with hash function $H$ used above. What is the security of this scheme? (Similar to above we have 120-t bit security after $2^t$ signatures because $\frac{256\cdot 2^t}{2^{128}}$)

I think if we use keyed hash OR bitmasks here, the security of this scheme will be 128-bit. So why we need both?

OR, what is the security of SPHINCS+ without keyed hash or bitmasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think if we use keyed hash OR bitmasks here, the security of this scheme will be 128-bit. So why we need both?

Actually, we don't.  Sphincs+ (at least, the round 3 version) has two sets of parameter sets, "simple" and "robust".  Simple only has the "keyed hash" (which I will interpret at the address structure which is included in every PRF, F, H and T evaluation; not really a key, as it is not secret), while robust has both the keyed hash and bitmasks.

Why is this?  It comes down to provable properties; simple has 128-bit security (for Level 1 parameter sets) if we assume that the hash function acts like a random Oracle; for robust, we get that security level on the weaker assumption that computing second preimages of the hash function takes $2^{128}$ time.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification. I still cannot find any collision attacks on hash based schemes. The paper "Digital Signatures Out of Second-Preimage
Resistant Hash Functions" says that "We propose a new construction for Merkle authentication
trees which does not require collision resistant hash functions;". Are there any schemes the security relies on the collision resistant hash functions. What is the case for my examples above?

Comment: Another interesting sentence from ia.cr/2017/349:
"XMSS uses a variant of WOTS (WOTS+ [13]) that eliminates the requirement for a collision resistant hash function." 

Why the securtity of WOTS suffers from collisions whereas WOTS+ not.